# using va_start in case of 0 variable parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

How does the `va_start` function work if I don't pass any variable parameters?

Example:

```
void check_varargs(char *test, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    // What happens here if there are no variable arguments provided as in line 9?
    va_start(args, test);
    va_end(args);
}
int main()
{
    check_varargs("testing 0 variable parameters"); // line 9
    check_varargs("testing 1 variable parameters", 1);
}
```

I am using a static code analysis tool, which is giving me an error on the line with `va_end` saying, incorrect sizeof expression. I am not sure what the error means but I am suspicious that it is because of the function call on line 9. Please help.

Comment: Have you ever said `printf("Hello world\n");`? That works, too...

Comment: (Also, does the error go away when you remove line 9?)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. It might be a false positive .. . clang++ doesn't report any errors.

Comment: agree that this seems to be a bug with the static code analysis tool

Comment: It's running without any errors